# wpdb prepare was called incorrectly, it must have a placeholder

Tags: php, wordpress

Hope you doing well.

I'm developing new plugin which contains list of books. When I try to add new book to the list by following code

```
<?php
    //Get data from Table
    global $wpdb;
    $all_books = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT * from ".my_books_table()." ORDER by id DESC", ""       
        ), ARRAY_A
    );
?>
```

Im getting the following error. Please help me. Thanks in advance. 
[Please refer the below image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u76e.png)

Notice: wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.9.0.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mdb\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4778

Answer (score 0):

Please change this to

```
<?php
//Get data from Table
global $wpdb;
$all_books = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * from %s ORDER by id DESC", my_books_table() ), 
    ARRAY_A
);
?>
```

It should work. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks you @Sourabh Matolia..when im using your code i got the following issue.WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''my_books_table()' ORDER by id DESC' at line 1]

Comment: Can you share the exact code again?
Also, please show definition of "my_books_table" function

Comment: list-of-books.php contains this code `<?php
//Get data from Table
global $wpdb;
$all_books = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT * from %s ORDER by id DESC', "my_books_table()" ), 
    ARRAY_A
);
?>`  and function where i defined the wp_my_books table is   `function my_book_table() {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->prefix . "my_books"; //wp_my_books
  }`

Comment: OK you are calling the function in quotes which is wrong.
Please use the updated code above. That should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for immediate response but still showing the same issue bro..WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''wp_my_books' ORDER by id DESC' at line 1]
SELECT * from 'wp_my_books' ORDER by id DESC

Comment: Again SQL query should be "SELECT * from wp_my_books ORDER by id DESC" without a single quote for table name.